# Image dissapears when HTML is sent via Internet

Tags: html, image

I have some HTML file with an `<img src="..."></>` tag inside. I can open the HTML and see the image just fine. But when I sent this HTML file to someone (by email, Skype, or whatever), even to me, the image is no longer there. The error I get when I open the HTML that I sent to myself is:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

What may be causing the problem? I thought of uploading the image somewhere on the Internet, so there will be no problem with finding it when I point to it with a url.

Comment: It seems you already answered your question. The src has to point to somewhere that the file exists at. That means if it's a relative path, it needs to be in that relative location compared to where the HTML is opened from. If it's an absolute path, then you need to make sure the image is accessible to that person at that path. "Sending HTML" isn't a common thing to do. If you're creating a website, then you generally host it somewhere, and they go access it at that hosted location.

Comment: It's a relative path and the image is in the same folder where the html file is. But still does not show when I send it.

Comment: If you're trying to share source code for your site with another dev, then generally you would use source control software such as [Git](https://git-scm.com/). And any images accessed by a relative path would be contained within the source control.

Comment: I think you are right about the sending of HTML. It works when I do not send it. And I think there is actually no need to send html. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, when I go to Chrome browser on "Source", the png file is there. The image, however, is not displayed, but a message "Image from file:///tmp/mozilla_petar0/image.png"

Answer (score 0):

if the source of the image is on your computer and not using a url, then you will either need to upload the image source onto the web or email the image source to the recipient.

you also need to make sure to have the image source located in the correct location/directory